# Change the way artists are displayed in Play Music?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, music

I just got a Nexus 5 running Kit Kat. The music app (Play Music) is beautiful, but not the most effiient in terms of browsing. Right now, in the "artists" view it displays a captioned picture of each artist. I'd like it to display a simple list of artist names. Is there a way to do this?